# can we build an app for both wear OS and watch OS using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, wear-os, watchos

can we build an app for both wear OS and watch OS using flutter, to get heart rate, blood oxygen, step count, blood pressure, etc.

For design, there is only dependency for wear OS (wear plugin) in pub.dev. I can't find any dependency for both wear OS and watch OS

Answer (score 3):

You can't build WatchOS App with Third party UI framework. Since your codes runs in extension process. Apple exposed WatchOS UI to be handled by some kind of proxy interface(`WKInterfaceObject`, `SwiftUI`) while actual UI interface(`UIResponder`) is totally inaccessible.

So, CoreAnimation, `UIView`, MetalKit(flutter heavily use it) is not available.